# IIS 6 windows 2003 help installing SSL cert

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, iis, ssl

I requested a new ssl cert from godaddy which has been issued.
When try to install it in iis through the website directory security tab i get a "the pending certificate request for this response file was not found. this request may be cancelled. you cannot install selected response certificate using this wizard" error.

I may have run the wizard and deleted the pending request.

Is there any way i can install the certificate without getting a new one? (i hope so)

I have the original certrequest.txt file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error usually occurs because you have deleted pending request of the certificate. The only recourse is to request a new certificate and completely finish the request before anything "security related" is changed on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have deleted the pending request, you no longer have  the private key that is associated with that cert, so you cannot use it.

Your going to need to re-run the wizard and generate a new csr, and get a new cert. Many SSL providers will let you cancel your original cert and re-submit, if your within a few days of buying it, and you ask nice.

Comment: thanks sam. godaddy had a "re-key" option in the control panel so i didnt have to wait for human interaction . deleted the pending request and generated a new key and it gave me a new ssl cert.